# Repeatedly saving the result of Conv2D (tensorflow), overwriting the the same variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been following some tensorflow tutorials to polish up some CNN skills. For adding layers to a CNN I have always done it like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

but I've seen some examples that use some very counter-intuitive syntax to me, such as:

```
#Encoder
encoder_input = Input(shape=(256, 256, 1,))
encoder_output = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(encoder_input)
encoder_output = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_output)
encoder_output = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(encoder_output)
encoder_output = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_output)
encoder_output = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(encoder_output)
encoder_output = Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_output)
encoder_output = Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_output)
encoder_output = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoder_output)
```

I had just assumed that you had to define a model, and then using `model.add` you add layers using the appropriate layer function.

In the second block of code, they don't even define a model. Then they just keep redefining the same variable over and over. If the `Con2D` function directly affects the tensorflow model, why save it to a variable?

I notice the `(encoder_input)` (is this a tuple?) or similar at the end of each line. Is this some special syntax I've not seen before? Is it general python syntax or specific to tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time, `Keras` provides you two ways to define your network model. May be you would like to look at these articles:

- [Keras Functional API Guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)
- [Keras Sequential API Guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/)

So, `encoder_input` in your case wasn't a tuple, it must be a Tensor. What you have done for doing `Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', strides=2)(encoder_input)` is you put `encoder_input` as a input for `Conv2D()`.

Comment: Thanks. I think the main issue is my lack of understanding of tensors and tensor graphs. Used them a bit in TF1 but I found them prohibitively complex.